# Как импортировать модуль chalk чтобы текст перекрасился в зеленый?

Tags: javascript, импорт

Что не так в этой строке?

```
import npm {green} from 'chalk';
```

Comment: Попробуйте без npm: `import {green} from 'chalk';`

Comment: SyntaxError: Named export 'green' not found. The requested module 'chalk' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.  
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:
вот что выдает

Comment: Тогда попробуйте `import chalk from 'chalk';`, а потом используйте `chalk.green()`.

Answer (score 0):

у меня работает так:

```
const chalk = require('chalk');
const log = console.log;
const error = chalk.bold.red;

 log(chalk.green.underline.bold(hashRole));
```

Была подобная проблема, из-за какой-то темы в VSCode.